# Trigger to Fire at a Specific Time and not on Event

Tags: trigger

I have a trigger that updates an account field with a count of custom objects that are linked to the account. The custom object are only linked if they are less than 1 year old. How can I fire the trigger daily to run for all the custom object records that meet the criteria?

```
    public class EncountersCountClass implements Database.Batchable<sOBject>, Schedulable {
    public void execute(SchedulableContext context) {
        Database.executeBatch(this);
    }
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        String notes1 = 'COVID';
            notes1 = '%'+notes1+'%';
        String notes2 = 'PCR';
            notes2 = '%'+notes2+'%';
        String query = 'SELECT Id, Account__c, Age__c, Notes__c FROM Encounters__c WHERE Age__c < 366 AND (Notes__c LIKE:notes1 OR Notes__c LIKE:notes2)';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<Encounters__c> enc) {
        List<Account> accts = new List<Account>();
        for(Encounters__c enc2 : enc){
            Account acct2 = enc2.Account__r;
            if(acct2 == null) continue;
            acct2.Encounters__c = acct2.Encounters__c.size();
        accts.add(acct2);
        }
        update accts;
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't "run a trigger daily." Triggers always execute in response to a DML operation. What you're looking for is a Batchable class that runs on a schedule:

```
public class UpdateEncounters implements Database.Batchable<sOBject>, Schedulable {
    public void execute(SchedulableContext context) {
        Database.executeBatch(this);
    }
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Encounters__c]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Encounters__c[] scope) {
        update scope;
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        
    }
}
```

Once saved, schedule this from the UI or Execute Anonymous to have this run daily.

```
System.schedule('UpdateEncounters','0 0 0 * * ?',new UpdateEncounters());
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed to a batch class as you suggested, but I am running into an error on line 18:  "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void size() from the type Decimal". Is there something else I should use to update the Account with the number of records besides the size() method?

Comment: @J.Neilan Your code has multiple logic problems. Given what I think you're trying to do, you should query the *account* records, then use an AggregateResult query to update the values for each account efficiently. See [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/296907/2984) I wrote for an example batchable class that's very close to what you need.

Comment: Thanks, that was a big help!

Comment: @J.Neilan You're welcome!